# How to convert key to value in dictionary type?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about the convert key.

First, I have this type of word count in Data Frame.

[Example]

```
dict = {'forest': 10, 'station': 3, 'office': 7, 'park': 2}
```

I want to get this result.

[Result]

```
result = {'name': 'forest', 'value': 10,
          'name': 'station', 'value': 3,
          'name': 'office', 'value': 7,
          'name': 'park', 'value': 2}
```

Please check this issue.

Comment: `dict` cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: @bonbon could you please give us some info about how you will be using `result`? there seems to be some misconception from your side, or maybe the question is incorrectly stated.

Comment: You could have a dictionary of dictionaries however: `{1: {'name': 'forest', 'value': 10}, 2: {'name': 'station', 'value': 3}}`

Comment: @Andreas I think this structure right.

Comment: @Selnay Sorry, I want to get like this {1: {'name': 'forest', 'value': 10}, 2: {'name': 'station', 'value': 3}}

Comment: @Rakesh Well, I know that... So I'm very embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

As Rakesh said:

> dict cannot have duplicate keys

The closest way to achieve what you want is to build something like that

```py
my_dict = {'forest': 10, 'station': 3, 'office': 7, 'park': 2}

result = list(map(lambda x: {'name': x[0], 'value': x[1]}, my_dict.items()))
```

You will get

```py
result = [
    {'name': 'forest', 'value': 10},
    {'name': 'station', 'value': 3},
    {'name': 'office', 'value': 7},
    {'name': 'park', 'value': 2},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Rakesh said, You can't have duplicate values in the dictionary
You can simply try this.

```
dict = {'forest': 10, 'station': 3, 'office': 7, 'park': 2}
result = {}
count = 0;
for key in dict:
    result[count] = {'name':key, 'value': dict[key]} 
    count = count + 1;

print(result)
```